# How to extract specific fields from mongodb in a specific time range?

Tags: mongodb

I have a huge mongodb collection and I am trying to export only specific fields from my mongodb but everything is getting exported in csv. I used following query to return all data in **moduleName, time and device_ip**(field in events array) field

```
mongoexport --host host-ipaddress --port 27017 --username admin --password password@123 --authenticationDatabase admin --db servername --collection alert --fields 'originalAlert.moduleName:1,originalAlert.time:1,originalAlert.events.0.device_ip:1' --query '{"receivedTime":{$gte:new Date(1583020800000), $lt:new Date(1585612800000)}}' --out /tmp/test.csv
```

Below is one object from **alert** collection in mongodb

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5e4bbb89208a6a8a435e064e"),
"receivedTime" : ISODate("2020-02-18T10:25:13.111Z"),
"status" : "GROUPED_IN_INCIDENT",
"originalHeaders" : {
    "name" : "Name of the Alert",
    "description" : null,
    "version" : 0,
    "severity" : 5,
    "timestamp" : NumberLong(1582021513108),
    "signatureId" : "30a9fedd3a7cb83dd66436057dd11445c6adfd242849c3813b38e62399128fd8",
    "deviceVendor" : "ABC",
    "deviceProduct" : "XYZ",
    "deviceVersion" : "123"
},
"originalAlert" : {
    "severity" : 5,
    "eventSourceId" : "x.x.x.x:50005:406265417822",
    "respondEnabled" : true,
    "moduleType" : "BASIC",
    "engineUri" : "Some Value",
    "moduleName" : "Name of the Alert",
    "suppressMessageBus" : false,
    "transientAlert" : false,
    "notificationReasons" : [ 
        "Some-Value", 
        "Some-Value.2"
    ],
    "actualEventsCount" : 3,
    "instanceId" : "30a9fedd3a7cb83dd66436057dd11445c6adfd242849c3813b38e62399128fd8",
    "statement" : "Module_5d7ccff0f28050b535cad89b_Alert",
    "id" : "9bef15ce-7dc5-4445-838f-79d78d2d6ea6",
    "time" : "Feb 18, 2020 10:25:13 AM UTC",
    "moduleId" : "5d7ccff0f28050b535cad89b",
    "events" : [ 
        {
            "msg" : "sshd[4719444]: Failed password for invalid user ISTOPR from x.x.x.x port 58134 ssh2",
            "event_byte_size" : 386,
            "ec_activity" : "Logon",
            "header_id" : "0013",
            "alias_host" : [ 
                "some-hostname"
            ],
            "event_cat_name" : "User.Activity.Failed Logins",
            "ip_src" : "x.x.x.x",
            "device_type" : "aix",
            "sessionid" : NumberLong(406265417822),
            "medium" : 32,
            "inv_context" : [ 
                "audit", 
                "compliance", 
                "authentication"
            ],
            "rid" : NumberLong(444833155418),
            "feed_name" : [ 
                "investigation"
            ],
            "event_cat" : 1401030000,
            "forward_ip" : "x.x.x.x",
            "alert_id" : [ 
                "account:logon-failure"
            ],
            "client" : "sshd",
            "com_rsa_asoc_streams_source_trail" : [ 
                "admin@x.x.x.x:50005.deployed-rules-sa-managed"
            ],
            "msg_id" : "00003:05",
            "device_disc" : 55,
            "com_rsa_asoc_streams_stream" : "deployed-rules-sa-managed-stream",
            "lc_cid" : "some-id",
            "ec_subject" : "User",
            "event_source_id" : "x.x.x.x:50005:406265417822",
            "com_rsa_asoc_streams_arrival_sequence" : 1789715,
            "esa_time" : NumberLong(1582021513102),
            "ec_theme" : "Authentication",
            "com_rsa_asoc_streams_arrival_timestamp" : NumberLong(1582021512436),
            "device_disc_type" : "aix",
            "inv_category" : [ 
                "assurance", 
                "identity"
            ],
            "device_ip" : "x.x.x.x",
            "ip_srcport" : 58134,
            "event_desc" : "Password failed",
            "user_dst" : "invalid user ISTOPR",
            "size" : 210,
            "netname" : [ 
                "private src"
            ],
            "device_class" : "Unix",
            "time" : NumberLong(1582021395000),
            "ec_outcome" : "Failure",
            "did" : "some-did"
        }, 
        {
            "msg" : "sshd[4719444]: Failed password for invalid user ISTOPR from x.x.x.x port 58134 ssh2",
            "event_byte_size" : 386,
            "ec_activity" : "Logon",
            "header_id" : "0013",
            "alias_host" : [ 
                "some-hostname"
            ],
            "event_cat_name" : "User.Activity.Failed Logins",
            "ip_src" : "x.x.x.x",
            "device_type" : "aix",
            "sessionid" : NumberLong(406265417824),
            "medium" : 32,
            "inv_context" : [ 
                "audit", 
                "compliance", 
                "authentication"
            ],
            "rid" : NumberLong(444833155420),
            "feed_name" : [ 
                "investigation"
            ],
            "event_cat" : 1401030000,
            "forward_ip" : "x.x.x.x",
            "alert_id" : [ 
                "account:logon-failure"
            ],
            "client" : "sshd",
            "com_rsa_asoc_streams_source_trail" : [ 
                "admin@x.x.x.x:50005.deployed-rules-sa-managed"
            ],
            "msg_id" : "00003:05",
            "device_disc" : 55,
            "com_rsa_asoc_streams_stream" : "deployed-rules-sa-managed-stream",
            "lc_cid" : "some-id",
            "ec_subject" : "User",
            "event_source_id" : "x.x.x.x:50005:406265417824",
            "com_rsa_asoc_streams_arrival_sequence" : 1789717,
            "esa_time" : NumberLong(1582021513103),
            "ec_theme" : "Authentication",
            "com_rsa_asoc_streams_arrival_timestamp" : NumberLong(1582021512436),
            "device_disc_type" : "aix",
            "inv_category" : [ 
                "assurance", 
                "identity"
            ],
            "device_ip" : "x.x.x.x",
            "ip_srcport" : 58134,
            "event_desc" : "Password failed",
            "user_dst" : "invalid user ISTOPR",
            "size" : 210,
            "netname" : [ 
                "private src"
            ],
            "device_class" : "Unix",
            "time" : NumberLong(1582021395000),
            "ec_outcome" : "Failure",
            "did" : "some-did"
        }, 
        {
            "msg" : "sshd[4719444]: Failed password for invalid user ISTOPR from x.x.x.x port 58134 ssh2",
            "event_byte_size" : 386,
            "ec_activity" : "Logon",
            "header_id" : "0013",
            "alias_host" : [ 
                "some-hostname"
            ],
            "event_cat_name" : "User.Activity.Failed Logins",
            "ip_src" : "x.x.x.x",
            "device_type" : "aix",
            "sessionid" : NumberLong(406265417826),
            "medium" : 32,
            "inv_context" : [ 
                "audit", 
                "compliance", 
                "authentication"
            ],
            "rid" : NumberLong(444833155422),
            "feed_name" : [ 
                "investigation"
            ],
            "event_cat" : 1401030000,
            "forward_ip" : "x.x.x.x",
            "alert_id" : [ 
                "account:logon-failure"
            ],
            "client" : "sshd",
            "com_rsa_asoc_streams_source_trail" : [ 
                "admin@x.x.x.x:50005.deployed-rules-sa-managed"
            ],
            "msg_id" : "00003:05",
            "device_disc" : 55,
            "com_rsa_asoc_streams_stream" : "deployed-rules-sa-managed-stream",
            "lc_cid" : "some-id",
            "ec_subject" : "User",
            "event_source_id" : "x.x.x.x:50005:406265417826",
            "com_rsa_asoc_streams_arrival_sequence" : 1789719,
            "esa_time" : NumberLong(1582021513103),
            "ec_theme" : "Authentication",
            "com_rsa_asoc_streams_arrival_timestamp" : NumberLong(1582021512436),
            "device_disc_type" : "aix",
            "inv_category" : [ 
                "assurance", 
                "identity"
            ],
            "device_ip" : "x.x.x.x",
            "ip_srcport" : 58134,
            "event_desc" : "Password failed",
            "user_dst" : "invalid user ISTOPR",
            "size" : 210,
            "netname" : [ 
                "private src"
            ],
            "device_class" : "Unix",
            "time" : NumberLong(1582021395000),
            "ec_outcome" : "Failure",
            "did" : "some-did"
        }
    ],
    "suppressNotification" : false
},
"alert" : {
    "groupby_source_device_mac_address" : "",
    "user_summary" : [ 
        "invalid user ISTOPR"
    ],
    "source" : "Event Stream Analysis",
    "type" : [ 
        "Log"
    ],
    "groupby_user_src" : "",
    "groupby_source_country" : "",
    "grouby_src_device_dns_domain" : "",
    "grouby_detector_dns_hostname" : "",
    "groupby_analysis_file" : "",
    "groupby_filename" : "",
    "groupby_source_username" : "",
    "groupby_detector_ip" : "x.x.x.x",
    "events" : [ 
        {
            "agent_id" : "",
            "data" : [ 
                {
                    "filename" : "",
                    "size" : 210,
                    "hash" : ""
                }
            ],
            "destination" : {
                "path" : "",
                "file_SHA256" : "",
                "filename" : "",
                "launch_argument" : "",
                "device" : {
                    "compliance_rating" : "",
                    "netbios_name" : "",
                    "port" : "",
                    "mac_address" : "",
                    "criticality" : "",
                    "asset_type" : "",
                    "ip_address" : "",
                    "facility" : "",
                    "business_unit" : "",
                    "geolocation" : {
                        "country" : "",
                        "city" : "",
                        "latitude" : null,
                        "organization" : "",
                        "domain" : "",
                        "longitude" : null
                    }
                },
                "user" : {
                    "email_address" : "",
                    "ad_username" : "",
                    "ad_domain" : "",
                    "username" : "invalid user ISTOPR"
                },
                "hash" : ""
            },
            "description" : "Password failed",
            "domain_src" : "",
            "device_type" : "aix",
            "event_source" : "x.x.x.x:50005",
            "source" : {
                "path" : "",
                "file_SHA256" : "",
                "filename" : "",
                "launch_argument" : "",
                "device" : {
                    "compliance_rating" : "",
                    "netbios_name" : "",
                    "port" : 58134,
                    "mac_address" : "",
                    "criticality" : "",
                    "asset_type" : "",
                    "ip_address" : "x.x.x.x",
                    "facility" : "",
                    "business_unit" : "",
                    "geolocation" : {
                        "country" : "",
                        "city" : "",
                        "latitude" : null,
                        "organization" : "",
                        "domain" : "",
                        "longitude" : null
                    }
                },
                "user" : {
                    "email_address" : "",
                    "ad_username" : "",
                    "ad_domain" : "",
                    "username" : ""
                },
                "hash" : ""
            },
            "type" : "Log",
            "analysis_file" : "",
            "enrichment" : "",
            "user_src" : "",
            "hostname" : "some-hostname",
            "analysis_service" : "",
            "file" : "",
            "detected_by" : "Unix-aix,x.x.x.x",
            "process_vid" : "",
            "host_src" : "",
            "action" : "",
            "operating_system" : "",
            "alias_ip" : "",
            "from" : "x.x.x.x:58134",
            "timestamp" : ISODate("2020-02-18T10:23:15.000Z"),
            "event_source_id" : "406265417822",
            "related_links" : [ 
                {
                    "type" : "investigate_original_event",
                    "url" : "/investigation/host/x.x.x.x:50005/navigate/event/AUTO/406265417822"
                }, 
                {
                    "type" : "investigate_destination_domain",
                    "url" : "/investigation/x.x.x.x:50005/navigate/query/alias.host%3D'some-hostname'%2Fdate%2F2020-02-18T10%3A13%3A15.000Z%2F2020-02-18T10%3A33%3A15.000Z"
                }
            ],
            "port_dst" : "",
            "domain_dst" : "",
            "user_dst" : "invalid user ISTOPR",
            "host_dst" : "",
            "size" : 210,
            "domain" : "some-hostname",
            "user_account" : "",
            "to" : "",
            "category" : "",
            "detector" : {
                "device_class" : "Unix",
                "ip_address" : "x.x.x.x",
                "product_name" : "aix"
            },
            "user" : "invalid user ISTOPR",
            "analysis_session" : "",
            "username" : ""
        }, 
        {
            "agent_id" : "",
            "data" : [ 
                {
                    "filename" : "",
                    "size" : 210,
                    "hash" : ""
                }
            ],
            "destination" : {
                "path" : "",
                "file_SHA256" : "",
                "filename" : "",
                "launch_argument" : "",
                "device" : {
                    "compliance_rating" : "",
                    "netbios_name" : "",
                    "port" : "",
                    "mac_address" : "",
                    "criticality" : "",
                    "asset_type" : "",
                    "ip_address" : "",
                    "facility" : "",
                    "business_unit" : "",
                    "geolocation" : {
                        "country" : "",
                        "city" : "",
                        "latitude" : null,
                        "organization" : "",
                        "domain" : "",
                        "longitude" : null
                    }
                },
                "user" : {
                    "email_address" : "",
                    "ad_username" : "",
                    "ad_domain" : "",
                    "username" : "invalid user ISTOPR"
                },
                "hash" : ""
            },
            "description" : "Password failed",
            "domain_src" : "",
            "device_type" : "aix",
            "event_source" : "x.x.x.x:50005",
            "source" : {
                "path" : "",
                "file_SHA256" : "",
                "filename" : "",
                "launch_argument" : "",
                "device" : {
                    "compliance_rating" : "",
                    "netbios_name" : "",
                    "port" : 58134,
                    "mac_address" : "",
                    "criticality" : "",
                    "asset_type" : "",
                    "ip_address" : "x.x.x.x",
                    "facility" : "",
                    "business_unit" : "",
                    "geolocation" : {
                        "country" : "",
                        "city" : "",
                        "latitude" : null,
                        "organization" : "",
                        "domain" : "",
                        "longitude" : null
                    }
                },
                "user" : {
                    "email_address" : "",
                    "ad_username" : "",
                    "ad_domain" : "",
                    "username" : ""
                },
                "hash" : ""
            },
            "type" : "Log",
            "analysis_file" : "",
            "enrichment" : "",
            "user_src" : "",
            "hostname" : "some-hostname",
            "analysis_service" : "",
            "file" : "",
            "detected_by" : "Unix-aix,x.x.x.x",
            "process_vid" : "",
            "host_src" : "",
            "action" : "",
            "operating_system" : "",
            "alias_ip" : "",
            "from" : "x.x.x.x:58134",
            "timestamp" : ISODate("2020-02-18T10:23:15.000Z"),
            "event_source_id" : "406265417824",
            "related_links" : [ 
                {
                    "type" : "investigate_original_event",
                    "url" : "/investigation/host/x.x.x.x:50005/navigate/event/AUTO/406265417824"
                }, 
                {
                    "type" : "investigate_destination_domain",
                    "url" : "/investigation/x.x.x.x:50005/navigate/query/alias.host%3D'some-hostname'%2Fdate%2F2020-02-18T10%3A13%3A15.000Z%2F2020-02-18T10%3A33%3A15.000Z"
                }
            ],
            "port_dst" : "",
            "domain_dst" : "",
            "user_dst" : "invalid user ISTOPR",
            "host_dst" : "",
            "size" : 210,
            "domain" : "some-hostname",
            "user_account" : "",
            "to" : "",
            "category" : "",
            "detector" : {
                "device_class" : "Unix",
                "ip_address" : "x.x.x.x",
                "product_name" : "aix"
            },
            "user" : "invalid user ISTOPR",
            "analysis_session" : "",
            "username" : ""
        }, 
        {
            "agent_id" : "",
            "data" : [ 
                {
                    "filename" : "",
                    "size" : 210,
                    "hash" : ""
                }
            ],
            "destination" : {
                "path" : "",
                "file_SHA256" : "",
                "filename" : "",
                "launch_argument" : "",
                "device" : {
                    "compliance_rating" : "",
                    "netbios_name" : "",
                    "port" : "",
                    "mac_address" : "",
                    "criticality" : "",
                    "asset_type" : "",
                    "ip_address" : "",
                    "facility" : "",
                    "business_unit" : "",
                    "geolocation" : {
                        "country" : "",
                        "city" : "",
                        "latitude" : null,
                        "organization" : "",
                        "domain" : "",
                        "longitude" : null
                    }
                },
                "user" : {
                    "email_address" : "",
                    "ad_username" : "",
                    "ad_domain" : "",
                    "username" : "invalid user ISTOPR"
                },
                "hash" : ""
            },
            "description" : "Password failed",
            "domain_src" : "",
            "device_type" : "aix",
            "event_source" : "x.x.x.x:50005",
            "source" : {
                "path" : "",
                "file_SHA256" : "",
                "filename" : "",
                "launch_argument" : "",
                "device" : {
                    "compliance_rating" : "",
                    "netbios_name" : "",
                    "port" : 58134,
                    "mac_address" : "",
                    "criticality" : "",
                    "asset_type" : "",
                    "ip_address" : "x.x.x.x",
                    "facility" : "",
                    "business_unit" : "",
                    "geolocation" : {
                        "country" : "",
                        "city" : "",
                        "latitude" : null,
                        "organization" : "",
                        "domain" : "",
                        "longitude" : null
                    }
                },
                "user" : {
                    "email_address" : "",
                    "ad_username" : "",
                    "ad_domain" : "",
                    "username" : ""
                },
                "hash" : ""
            },
            "type" : "Log",
            "analysis_file" : "",
            "enrichment" : "",
            "user_src" : "",
            "hostname" : "some-hostname",
            "analysis_service" : "",
            "file" : "",
            "detected_by" : "Unix-aix,x.x.x.x",
            "process_vid" : "",
            "host_src" : "",
            "action" : "",
            "operating_system" : "",
            "alias_ip" : "",
            "from" : "x.x.x.x:58134",
            "timestamp" : ISODate("2020-02-18T10:23:15.000Z"),
            "event_source_id" : "406265417826",
            "related_links" : [ 
                {
                    "type" : "investigate_original_event",
                    "url" : "/investigation/host/x.x.x.x:50005/navigate/event/AUTO/406265417826"
                }, 
                {
                    "type" : "investigate_destination_domain",
                    "url" : "/investigation/x.x.x.x:50005/navigate/query/alias.host%3D'some-hostname'%2Fdate%2F2020-02-18T10%3A13%3A15.000Z%2F2020-02-18T10%3A33%3A15.000Z"
                }
            ],
            "port_dst" : "",
            "domain_dst" : "",
            "user_dst" : "invalid user ISTOPR",
            "host_dst" : "",
            "size" : 210,
            "domain" : "some-hostname",
            "user_account" : "",
            "to" : "",
            "category" : "",
            "detector" : {
                "device_class" : "Unix",
                "ip_address" : "x.x.x.x",
                "product_name" : "aix"
            },
            "user" : "invalid user ISTOPR",
            "analysis_session" : "",
            "username" : ""
        }
    ],
    "grouby_detector_dns_domain" : "",
    "host_summary" : [ 
        "x.x.x.x:58134"
    ],
    "groupby_username" : "",
    "grouby_src_device_dns_hostname" : "",
    "grouby_dst_usr_ad_username" : "",
    "groupby_file_sha_256" : "",
    "groupby_user_dst" : "invalid user ISTOPR",
    "groupby_os" : "",
    "grouby_src_usr_ad_domain" : "",
    "name" : "Multiple Failed AIX Logins detected",
    "groupby_host_src" : "",
    "groupby_analysis_service" : "",
    "groupby_destination_device_mac_address" : "",
    "groupby_version" : "0",
    "grouby_src_device_geolocation_domain" : "",
    "destination_country" : [],
    "groupby_type" : "Log",
    "grouby_src_device_netbios_name" : "",
    "groupby_device_type" : "aix",
    "groupby_domain" : "some-hostname",
    "grouby_dst_device_dns_hostname" : "",
    "groupby_destination_country" : "",
    "grouby_dst_usr_username" : "invalid user ISTOPR",
    "grouby_dst_usr_ad_domian" : "",
    "groupby_analysis_session" : "",
    "signature_id" : "30a9fedd3a7cb83dd66436057dd11445c6adfd242849c3813b38e62399128fd8",
    "groupby_data_hash" : "",
    "groupby_domain_dst" : "",
    "groupby_destination_ip" : "",
    "groupby_host_dst" : "",
    "grouby_dst_device_geolocation_domain" : "",
    "grouby_dst_device_netbios_name" : "",
    "groupby_source_ip" : "x.x.x.x",
    "groupby_detector_mac_address" : "",
    "timestamp" : ISODate("2020-02-18T10:25:13.108Z"),
    "severity" : 50.0,
    "related_links" : [ 
        {
            "type" : "investigate_session",
            "url" : "/investigation/x.x.x.x:50005/navigate/query/sessionid%3D406265417822%7C%7Csessionid%3D406265417824%7C%7Csessionid%3D406265417826"
        }, 
        {
            "type" : "investigate_device_ip",
            "url" : "/investigation/x.x.x.x:50005/navigate/query/device.ip%3D10.192.30.44%2Fdate%2F2020-02-18T10%3A13%3A15.000Z%2F2020-02-18T10%3A33%3A15.000Z"
        }, 
        {
            "type" : "investigate_src_ip",
            "url" : "/investigation/x.x.x.x:50005/navigate/query/ip.src%3D10.192.8.167%2Fdate%2F2020-02-18T10%3A13%3A15.000Z%2F2020-02-18T10%3A33%3A15.000Z"
        }, 
        {
            "type" : "investigate_destination_domain",
            "url" : "/investigation/x.x.x.x:50005/navigate/query/alias.host%3D'some-hostname'%2Fdate%2F2020-02-18T10%3A13%3A15.000Z%2F2020-02-18T10%3A33%3A15.000Z"
        }
    ],
    "risk_score" : 50.0,
    "grouby_dst_device_dns_domain" : "",
    "grouby_src_usr_ad_username" : "",
    "groupby_destination_port" : "",
    "groupby_c2domain" : "",
    "groupby_host_name" : "some-hostname",
    "source_country" : [],
    "groupby_domain_src" : "",
    "numEvents" : 3,
    "groupby_agent_id" : ""
},
"partOfIncident" : true,
"_class" : "com.rsa.asoc.respond.commons.domain.Alert",
"incidentCreated" : ISODate("2020-02-18T10:25:47.228Z"),
"incidentId" : "INC-1"
```

}

Sample Output:

[Sample Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F9HIC.jpg)

Please let me know where I did wrong.

Comment: Please paste a sample CSV output so that what gets exported is clear

Comment: Forgive me for this kind of image for sample output. Please understand it is big database and it is returning a big row of 54 Columns out of which I only want 3 columns hightlighted in red.

Comment: better to just post text. Also, please fix the json formatting

Comment: Text will confuse you and others. Please zoom the image to get its clear view.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `--csv` argument to `mongoexport` command.

As of MongoDB v4.2.2, the `--csv` is deprecated but will work. The more correct option would be to do a `--type=csv` as an argument to `mongoexport`

Also, I see there are issues in the way the fields argument and query argument are constructed.

```
mongoexport --host <host> --port <port> --db <db> --collection <collection> --type=csv --fields 'originalAlert.moduleName,originalAlert.time,originalAlert.events.0.device_ip' --out /tmp/test.csv
```

Produces results

```
originalAlert.moduleName,originalAlert.time,originalAlert.events.0.device_ip
Name of the Alert,"Feb 18, 2020 10:25:13 AM UTC",x.x.x.x
```

On adding the `--query`, I added a `--query '{"receivedTime":{"$gte": {"$date" : "<start-date>"}, "$lt": {"$date":"<end-date>"}}}'` to produce :

```
mongoexport --host <host> --port <port> --db <db> --collection <collection> --type=csv --fields 'originalAlert.moduleName,originalAlert.time,originalAlert.events.0.device_ip' --query '{"receivedTime":{"$gte": {"$date" : "2020-02-18T00:00:01Z"}, "$lt": {"$date":"2020-02-19T00:00:01Z"}}}' --out /tmp/test.csv
```

This does filter the records appropriately.

Comment: Thanks Deepak. I tried as you recommended to add ```--type=csv``` but it  exported 0 result. Also date format I used is in EPOCH time format that is working fine to fetch data from 1st March 2020 to 31st March 2020. Just not getting desired 3 fields instead I am getting everything of originalAlert object

Comment: @NitinMaurya : So if you have used timestamp, then you could just have the epoch time instead of the {$date:<>} component and it should work. Also, maybe drop the --query and test if it works or not. Please note the changes I have made to the fields arguments in the command I posted

Comment: Hi Deepak, tried removing query part too but still getting 0 records fetched.

Comment: @NitinMaurya Please post the full command. It is not possible to guess what could be wrong here